# Calling a method which throws exception

Tags: java

I  have this method that throws exception

```
public String Pipeit() throws TransformerException,   
TransformerConfigurationException,SAXException, IOException
```

i tried calling this method from a GUI

```
Pipe P = new Pipe (fname,x1name,x2name,x3name,oname);
     view.setText(P.Pipeit()throws TransformerConfigurationException,SAXException, 
        IOException))
```

It kept giving this error

- ')'  is expected.

Comment: Your method call is considered to be the method definition itself by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to write this with correct syntax:

```
Pipe P = new Pipe (fname,x1name,x2name,x3name,oname);
try {
    view.setText(P.Pipeit());
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    //log/handle the exception
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    //log/handle the exception
} catch (SAXException e) {
    //log/handle the exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    //log/handle the exception
}
```

Comment: i tried your method and it gave this error: unreported exception javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: must be caught or declared to be thrown.. ive added it

Comment: Fixed. I missed an exception (sorry I was pulled away by someone before I could add this comment)

Answer (score 2):

```
throws TransformerConfigurationException,SAXException, IOException
```

should only be specified when you declare the method, not when you call it.

Also, variable names should by convention begin with a lower-case letter, and as @ssloan points out, method names should be in lower camelCase.
Change your code to

```
Pipe p = new Pipe (fname,x1name,x2name,x3name,oname);
view.setText(p.pipeIt());
```

Comment: While we're on conventions, method names should be in lower camelCase. So your method should be pipeIt(...) not Pipeit.

Answer (score 0):

While invoking method, you don't need to include entire method signature ( in this case throws clause).

```
view.setText(P.Pipeit()throws TransformerConfigurationException,SAXException, 
            IOException))
```

should be

```
 view.setText(new P().Pipeit())
```